# bad allocation exception in c++ as allocating memory for char*

Tags: c++

I am practicing C++.

I implement the String class in two versions. in the first version the text is saved in a array. in the second version, the text is saved in a dynamic allocation memory. the second version inherits 
the first.

the first version works OK.
in the second version, in the first line of the concat function, i get a bad allocation exception.

this is the code:

```
        #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class String{

    protected:
        enum{SIZE=256};
        void setLen(const int length)
        {
            m_len = length;
        }
    private:
        int m_len;
        char m_text [SIZE];

    public:

        String()
        {
            m_len = 0;
            strcpy_s (m_text, 1, "");
        }
        String(const char* text)
        {
            m_len = strlen(text);
            strcpy_s (m_text, strlen(text) + 1,  text);
        }
        const char* get() const
        {
            return m_text;
        }
        virtual void set(char* text)
        {
            strcpy_s (m_text, strlen(text) + 1, text);
        }
        int getLen() const
        {
            return m_len;
        }
        virtual void concat(const String &s)
        {
            strcat_s(m_text, strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get()) + 1, s.m_text);
        }
        bool equal(const String &s)const
        {
            return strcmp(s.m_text, m_text);
        }
        bool operator ==(const String &s)const
        {
            return strcmp(s.m_text, m_text);
        }
        virtual void print()const
        {
            cout<<m_text;
        }


    };

    class PointString :public String {
        char* m_text;
    public:
        PointString()
        {
            setLen(0);
            m_text = new char[1];
            strcpy_s(m_text, 1,"");
        }
        PointString(const char* text)
        {
            setLen(strlen(text));
            m_text = new char[strlen(text)+1];
            strcpy_s(m_text, strlen(text)+1 ,text);
        }
        void set(char* text)
        {
            delete [] m_text;
            setLen(strlen(text));
            m_text = new char[strlen(text)+1];
        }
        void concat(const String &s)
        {
            char *temp = new char[strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get())];
            strcpy_s(temp, SIZE, m_text);
            strcat_s(m_text,strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get()) + 1, s.get());
            delete [] m_text;
            m_text = temp;
        }
        void print()const
        {
            cout<<m_text<<endl;
        }
    };

void main()
{
    PointString str("1234");
    str.print();
    str.concat("8901");
    str.print();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You initialize `m_text` to a `new char[]`, but you don't necessarily put a `'\0'` in the array (depending on which constructor is used). If there's no null terminator, the behavior of `strlen` is undefined.

Comment: I must also point out the design problem of making `PointerString` inherit the character array from `String`.

Comment: unrelated, but `strcpy_s` is Microsoft and not standard C++

Comment: Advice -- If you're going to implement a string class, it's worthless if you can't copy and assign string objects to each other.  `PointString str2 = str;`  From what you posted, this will not work correctly.

Comment: Why do you do a `strcpy_s` with `SIZE` as the length in `PointString::PointString(const char*)`? It may lead to a buffer over/under run. It should be what `strlen` returned + 1.

Comment: You are missing a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor in the second version.  As soon as you did `PointString str2 = str;` you are going to have issues with memory leaks.

Comment: thanks you all for your comments. except of the strcpy_s that i use because the VS demands, i changed the code (also in the question) as you suggest, and it still gives the same exception.

Comment: @ZagGol You've edited the code, but you're still missing the destructor, thus you still have memory leaks.  Also, just because the edited code shows main() no longer doing a copy doesn't mean you shouldn't address the problem.  BTW, the `main` function returns `int`, not `void`, and the correct header for C-style string functions is `<cstring>`, not `<string>`

Comment: Also what is `PointString::set()` supposed to do? Because right now it's just allocating some memory but never copying any data into it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this in your `concat` call:

```
    char *temp = new char[strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get())]; // 1
    strcpy_s(temp, SIZE, m_text);  
    strcat_s(m_text, strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get()) + 1, s.get());  // 2
    delete[] m_text;
    m_text = temp;
```

For issue `// 1`, you did not allocate enough space for the string.  You forgot the terminating NULL entry.

For issue `// 2`, you are concatenating onto `m_text` before it is sized properly.

Using standard string functions, the changes below cause no issues:

```
    char *temp = new char[strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get()) + 1];
    strcpy(temp, m_text);
    strcat(temp, s.get());
    delete[] m_text;
    m_text = temp;
```

Using the Microsoft safe string functions, you should save the length of the new string in a variable and use it in each call.  Specifying `SIZE` doesn't seem to be correct.  Here is what works for me:

```
void concat(const String &s)
{
    size_t sz = strlen(m_text) + strlen(s.get()) + 1;
    char *temp = new char[sz];
    strcpy_s(temp, sz, m_text);
    strcat_s(temp, sz, s.get());
    delete[] m_text;
    m_text = temp;
}
```

---

There are other issues with your code.  One is the lack of a destructor, thus you have memory leaks whenever you create a `PointString`.  The other issue is that copying and assigning a `PointString` to another `PointString` will not work correctly due to a lack of a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

Please read up on the above topics, as a string class that cannot make copies of themselves is practically not worth using (if you were going to use it), on top of not being usable at all due to the memory leaks present (no destructor).

If you remove yourself from the "homework" phase, the `std::string` class does all of the work you're doing now, except more safe and efficient.